# How can I divide tile-based space into largest the possible squares?

Tags: tiles, tilemap, space-partitioning

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to take a tilemap like the top image and divide it into square spaces like the colored areas in the second image.

Comment: This has been discussed in StackOverflow. Do not expect game runtime-speed solving, will take seconds. Have a look at the accepted answer in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963156/optimal-filling-of-grid-figure-with-squares

Comment: An approach that doesn't use mixed integer programming might be to try and fit squares starting form NxN, (N-1)x(N-1), etc until there is no free space.